# Matchit not working in customed filetype

Tags: vim

I installed matchit.vim this plugin.it works well for html tags in the PHP type files, but when I open a *.ihtml type file. I can't use % to jump between the html tags.How can I fix this?

Comment: Use `:set filetype=html`.

Comment: thanks,it works,But why set syntax=html not working?

Comment: Because matchit is *filetype*-dependent, not *syntax*-dependent.

Answer (score 2):

The matchit plugin is configured in `$VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin/html.vim`. Your `*.ihtml` files apparently have another *filetype*. You have these options:

#### Change filetype detection

If those are basically HTML files, and you want to reuse syntax and filetype settings, just adapt your filetype detection:

```
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.ihtml html
```

#### Copy matchit config to separate filetype

Else, create a file `~/.vim/ftplugin/{filetype}.vim` (determine `{filetype}` via `:setlocal filetype?`), and copy the matchit HTML configuration in there:

```
if exists("loaded_matchit")
    let b:match_ignorecase = 1
    let b:match_words = '<:>,' .
    \ '<\@<=[ou]l\>[^>]*\%(>\|$\):<\@<=li\>:<\@<=/[ou]l>,' .
    \ '<\@<=dl\>[^>]*\%(>\|$\):<\@<=d[td]\>:<\@<=/dl>,' .
    \ '<\@<=\([^/][^ \t>]*\)[^>]*\%(>\|$\):<\@<=/\1>'
endif
```